# Passing a row in a 2D array to a function using a pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, prototype, multidimensional-array

I need to write a program that scans in a 2D array and then finds the minimum value in each row by using a function.
The prototype `int RowMin(int *prow, int ncols)` was given in the instructions. My problem is that I don't know for sure how to use the pointer. This was my best guess and it's not correct. The program crashes after I enter in the values of the array.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int RowMin(int *prow, int c);

int main()
{
    int a[MAX][MAX];
    int r, c, min;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Enter number of rows & columns of array:\n");
         scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    printf("\nEnter elements of 2-D array:\n");
         for(i=0; i<r; i++)
         {
                  for(j=0; j<c; j++)
                  {
                           scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
                  }
         }  
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        min = RowMin(i, c);
        printf("The min in row %d is %d",i, min);
    }    
    return 0;
}   

int RowMin(int *prow, int ncols)
{
    int temp, i;
    int a[*prow][ncols]; //this is where it is messing up
    temp = a[*prow][0];
    for(i=0; i<ncols; i++)
    {
        printf("Good5");
        if(temp > a[*prow][i])
        {
            temp = a[*prow][i];

        }    
    }    
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: You are passing an int (`i`) instead of a pointer.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings set to on, repair all that warnings  and then, eventually, if the problem persists come back here: you pass an `int` to the function, where you should pass an `int*`, you use `a[*pow][0]` out of bounds, you use  `a[*pow][0]` without initializing it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the address of the each row:

```
min = RowMin(a[i], c);
```

Then do this in your routine in order to find `min` in each row

```
 int RowMin(int *prow, int ncols)
    {
        int min=prow[0], i;

        for(i=0; i<ncols; i++)
        {

            if(min > prow[i])
            {
                min = prow[i];

            }    
        }    
        return min;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop

```
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    min = RowMin(i, c);
    printf("The min in row %d is %d",i, min);
}
```

you have to pass a row of the array to the function. So the call will look like

```
    min = RowMin( a[i], c );
```

Take into account that you should check that entered values of rows and columns are not greater than MAX. Or if your compiler supports variable length arrays you could use a variable length array when its sizes are set by entered values of r and c.

The function itself is also invalid. It can be written the following way

```
int RowMin( const int *prow, int ncols )
{
    int i = 0;
    int min = prow[i];

    while ( ++i < ncols )
    {
        if ( prow[i] < min )
        {
            min = prow[i];
        }    
    }    

    return min;
}
```

Correspondingly the function have to be declared like

```
int RowMin( const int *prow, int c );
```

Comment: You are finding max here

Comment: your condition is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The function call should look like this

`min = RowMin(&a[i],c)`

You should pass the address of each row.

The function should be modified like this

```
int minRow(int *ptr, int columns)
{
  //ptr has the address of each row
  int minElt = ptr[0]; //Contains the first Element

  for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
  {
      if( minElt > ptr[0] )
          minElt = ptr[0]
  }
  return minElt;
}
```